# JQuery not finishing before function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery script that runs on form submit. Two things happen, I change the value of the hidden input field and then make a call to the function EditPost(). For some reason, I think that the EditPost() function fires before the previous line of code is done. Is this possible, how can I fix it if so?

My JQuery:

```
$("#edit-post-collection-input").val(data);
EditPost();
```

NOTE: This is all wrapped in a document ready and a form submit event. Also, the function EditPost() and the variable data has already been declared.

Comment: not possible; javascript is single threaded

Comment: No. Let us see your HTML, please, obviously there's another problem in your code

Comment: What is the reason for you thinking that?

Comment: I bet It is running in that order. however your screen doesn't get updated till the end so you don't see the input updated right after the first statement.